# DLL Load failed error when installing opencv for Python 2.7

Tags: python, opencv

I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 and Python 2.7, precisely:

> Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:22:17) [MSC v.1500
>   32 bit (Intel)] on win32

the recent version of OpenCV library 3.4.2 isn't working and it produces the following error:

```
>>> import cv2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

So I downloaded older version OpenCV 3.4.1, copied cv2.pyd to C:/Python27/lib/site-packages and viola it works!

Now is this my fail or theirs? I downloaded VC++ x86 Redistributable 2015 and 2017, Python is also 32-bit, and I'm using a 32-bit version of OpenCV lib, so I don't think that's my issue, what's going on, does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

Try installing with pip?
I've never had an issue with a pip installation of cv2.

```
pip install opencv-python
```